# Allocating memory using AWE

Tags: c++, winapi, awe

I'm using 32bit Windows XP SP3 with PAE enabled and 8GB physical memory.

All i want is to use AWE to allocate memory from the dark side - i.e. the hidden 4GB - so i wrote i gave my user `Lock pages in memory` right then i wrote the following code:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

BOOL EnableAWE();

int main()
{
    if(!EnableAWE())
    {
        printf("Can not enable AWE on this system.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    HANDLE hProcess = GetCurrentProcess();
    SIZE_T byts = ~0u >> 1;
    LPVOID ptr = VirtualAllocEx(hProcess, NULL, byts, MEM_PHYSICAL | MEM_RESERVE, PAGE_READWRITE);

    if (ptr == NULL)
    {
        printf("Allocation failed for requested memory size.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    VirtualFreeEx(hProcess, ptr, 0, MEM_RELEASE);

    return 0;
}

BOOL EnableAWE()
{
    HANDLE hToken = NULL;

    TOKEN_PRIVILEGES tp;
    tp.PrivilegeCount = 1;
    tp.Privileges[0].Attributes = SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED;

    if(!OpenProcessToken(GetCurrentProcess(), TOKEN_QUERY | TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES, &hToken)) return FALSE;
    if (!LookupPrivilegeValue(NULL, SE_LOCK_MEMORY_NAME, &(tp.Privileges[0].Luid))) return FALSE;
    if (!AdjustTokenPrivileges(hToken, FALSE, &tp, sizeof(TOKEN_PRIVILEGES), NULL, NULL)) return FALSE;

    return TRUE;
}
```

the function `EnableAWE` always return true, but when i try to allocate the 2GB using `VirtualProtect` it fails with error code 87 which means `The parameter is incorrect.`

i don't know which parameter is incorrect.

thanks.

Comment: The number of bytes you are allocating is not a multiple of the page size. Call `GetSystemInfo` first.

Comment: the OS will round the bytes to the page size, that is what the MSDN says.

Comment: I thought large memory on 32 bit was limited to server editions of the OS

Comment: Perhaps you would like to try this MSDN sample code: [AWE Example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366531.aspx).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Um, `VirtualAlloc` does not allocate AWE memory. (`AllocateUserPhysicalPages` actually allocates the memory.) It reserves virtual address space into which AWE memory can be mapped. And your process does not have 2GB of available virtual address space.

Answer (score 0):

There's no call to VirtualProtect in the code that you posted. Also, did you compile with /LARGEADDRESSAWARE?

In any case, I suspect that you cannot get 2GB of contiguous address space on Win32, even with PAE. Try reducing byts and see if that helps.

Comment: /LARGEADDRESSAWARE won't change anything on 32 bit OS, unless the OS is booted with /3GB